# Form Button Disable Not Working On Submit

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I am trying to disable my button after a submit request is sent. I tried the example below, but it is not working as expected.

Why isn't this code working as expected?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#userSignUp').submit(function() {
    $("input[type='submit']", this).val("Please Wait...").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return true;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/sign-up" method="post" id="userSignUp">
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="login-sign-up-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were targeting `input`, instead target `button` which you were using.

```
$("button[type=submit]").val("Please Wait...").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this do it?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#userSignUp").submit(function (e) {

            //stop submitting the form to see the disabled button effect
            e.preventDefault();

            //disable the submit button
            $("#userSignUp").attr("disabled", true);

            return true;

        });
    });
```

Comment: This is also a workable solution. Didn't think of e.preventDefault(); in the initial process. Thanks for the help!